# PHP - preg_replace simplify?

Tags: php, preg-replace

haven't used regex replaces much and am not sure if how I have done this is the best way of doing it.
  Im trying to change eg:

```
'(.123.)' OR 123.)' OR '(.123
```

to

```
'.(123).' OR 123).' OR '.(123
```

must be an int in the middle.

```
preg_replace('/\.\)/', ').',preg_replace('/\(\./', '.(',preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]+\.)|(\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.)/', '($0)',$str)));
```

the code I have above works, just wondering if there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do more simply in two replacements, one for (. before a digit and one for .) after a digit?

```
$str=preg_replace('/\(\.(\d)/', '.($1', $str);
$str=preg_replace('/(\d)\.\)/', '$1).', $str);
```

It's even possible to do this in one go, but it looks uglier. Here I look for a number preceded by `(.` and optionally followed by `.)`, or optionally preceded by `(.` and followed by `.)`, then replace the whole lot with `.(number).` - this has the effect of turning `.(123` into `.(123).`, which you may or may not want...

```
$str=preg_replace('/\(\.(\d+)(?:\.\))?|(?:\(\.)?(\d+)\.\)/', '.($1$2).', $str);
```